# WCF service host cannot find any service metadata

Tags: .net, wcf

I've almost migrated service in ASMX in vb to new WCF 4.0 based, but I can't run it because I get an message at start:

```
WCF Service Host cannot find any service metadata. This may cause the client application to run improperly. Please check if metadate is enabled. Do you want to exit?
```

I don't know what's wrong with this app.config.

Could you look at it and help me?

```
WCF Service Host cannot find any service metadata. This may cause the client application to run improperly. Please check if metadate is enabled. Do you want to exit?

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="ExtraWS.My.MySettings" requirePermission="false" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ExtraWS.ExtraBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ExtraWS.ExtraBehavior" name="ExtraWS.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ExtraWS.Service1" name ="mex">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" closeTimeout="00:01:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" name="PostcodeLookupSoap" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message algorithmSuite="Default" clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" closeTimeout="00:01:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" name="C1WSSoap" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message algorithmSuite="Default" clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" closeTimeout="00:01:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" name="E1Soap" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message algorithmSuite="Default" clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://postcodews.mycompany.co.uk/PostcodeLookup.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PostcodeLookupSoap" contract="PostcodeService.PostcodeLookupSoap" name="PostcodeLookupSoap" />
      <endpoint address="https://C1.mycompany.co.uk/C1ws.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="C1WSSoap" contract="C1Service.C1WSSoap" name="C1WSSoap" />
      <endpoint address="https://E1uat.mycompany.co.uk/qbitE1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="E1Soap" contract="E1Service.E1Soap" name="E1Soap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*" />
      <add path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" verb="*" />
      <add path="*_AppService.axd" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" verb="*" />
      <add path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" verb="GET,HEAD" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <applicationSettings>
    <ExtraWS.My.MySettings>
      <setting name="AlwaysAuthenticate" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
    </ExtraWS.My.MySettings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <appSettings>
    SECRET/>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    SECRET/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

Is your WCF service a library (DLL)?  I ask because of the following line in the config file you posted:

`<!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->`

If your service is a DLL, then you'll need to post the `<system.serviceModel>` section in the host's config file.  For IIS, that would be the web.config file; for a Windows Service or self-hosted service, it would be the app.config file.  As the commented line above says, service libraries do not use their own config files, they utilize the host's config file.

Comment: Great notice Tim. I haven't access to code at the moment, but in Monday I'll check it. Thanks :)

Comment: The problem was with with DataContract attributer, or actuallny with lack of them. I figured out this thanks wcf tracing.

Comment: @user278618 : can you tell what was the solution as I am getting into the same issue

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember now, but I'm pretty sure some class hadn't the DataContract attribute

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Can somebody help out with the problem. Need a precise solution.

Answer (score 4):

Got the solution!

This problem was with the Service Name attribute. It was not able to find IService in the tag. I had changed the IService to some different name. Need to map the correct names.

Comment: Ran into a similar problem.  Remember the "Service Name" will be case-sensitive!  My working service broke when the namespace my service class was in changed to all uppercase.  Wasted a couple hours tracking it down.

Comment: yep, had the same issue - noticed that service name was with wavy line - renaming service class name through solution explorer did not rename it in App.Config file...

Answer (score 1):

In the Solution Explorer right click on app.config
1.this will open the configuration dialog.
2.Expand the service.
3.Select End point.
4.On the right side click on contract
5.this will open the application directory
6.open bin folder.double click on the dll and then select
the service
7.click on file menu and save it.

here hostissue is the namespace..so the service name should be hostissue.the class your implementing.

build the application and run it.